# Adding blocks to manager

Tags: c#, .net, piranha-cms

I am using piranha cms and would like to have some default blocks on certain pages that should allways show when creating a new page, is there a way to add this?

Im thinking something in the way of

```
[PageType(Title = "MyPage")]
public class MyPage : Page<MyPage>
{
    public TextField SomeText {get;set;}
}
```

so that when a manager creates a "MyPage" the textfield "SomeText" will be there by default

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, for future reference, use regions for this purpose:
https://piranhacms.org/docs/master/content/regions